# Javascript - Google closure annotation - Setting a type to anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, annotations, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to annotate my Javascript properly in order to avoid Google Closure messing up with my variables.

I am wondering if it is possible to strongly type an anonymous function to make sure the parameters of the function (which are externs in my case) are not renamed.

Here is an illustration

```
/** externs.js where I define my externs */
/** @interface a Json object returned by the server */
function MyServerResult() {}
/** @type {boolean} */
MyServerResult.prototype.error;
```

and in another file compiled with `externs.js` and `jquery.js` as externs.

```
$.get("url.php", function(data) {alert(data.error;}, "json");
```

I am trying to make sure the anonymous function `function(data)` has `@type {function(MyServerResult)}` so `error` is not renamed.

Can I do that directly or do I need to create a seperate function (that will probably be inlined by the compiler...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do:

```
/**
 * @param {MyServerResult} data
 */
var callback = function(data) {
  alert(data.error);
};
$.get("url.php", callback, "json");
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds very rational. I will try this out.

Comment: After testing, it does work in a sense that it prevents from renaming the members it is the most important. However, it generates a warning because data does not have the expected type, is there a way to remove this warning by some kind of 'casting'?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I did not know about the parenthesis around the variable. Your second version is the safest I guess.

Comment: Cool, removed the first version and left it with the second.